# .whl is not supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to install `hdbcli-2.3.99-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` that I have saved to local drive.

I am using next:

```
PS C:\Users\i326707\PycharmProjects\hdbcli> python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I run next:

```
pip install hdbcli-2.3.99-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

I get the following error:

> hdbcli-2.3.99-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not supported wheel on this platform

Comment: Wait... hdbcli? As in the SAP HANA client? Does that come in wheel format now? I thought it was only .zip or .tar.gz, depending on platform.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to install `hdbcli-2.3.99-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` with `Python 3.6.2`

The filename contains `cp27-cp27m` and `amd64` so you will need `Python 2.7 x64`

Similarly, for `hdbcli-2.3.99-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` you will need `Python 3.5 x64`

For your python version the wheel file's name should be `hdbcli-2.3.99-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`