# Cannot install .whl with pip, windows

Tags: python, mysql, pip, connector

Python version:

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) 
[MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>>
```

Pip version:

```
(venv) C:\ ... \PycharmProjects\TyreAnalsys>pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from c:\ ... \ tyres\pycharmprojects\tyreanalsys\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip (python 3.8)
```

Want to install mysqlclient using:

```
pip install Mysqlclient
```

but it always fails due to missing header files in the vs tools, so I'm trying to install the .whl file, but i have this issue instead:

[.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659519/whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

So the wheel I'm trying to install it using:

```
pip install D:/mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

but it says:

```
mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I tried the 64x version also, but nothing. Cheers

What am I missing? Cheers.

Comment: [Related specifically for `mysqlclient` on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146117/installing-mysqlclient-in-python-3-6-in-windows).

Comment: Can you give the output of `python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())"` and also try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: Why do you have 32-bit python anyway?