# Why I cant install mysqlclient?

Tags: python, mysql

[eror][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7n8R.png`C:\Users\busra\Downloads>pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7n8R.png%60C:%5CUsers%5Cbusra%5CDownloads%3Epip) install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

C:\Users\busra\Downloads>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

C:\Users\busra\Downloads>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

C:\Users\busra\Downloads>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... \  WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1254
error`

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Python are you using?

First, try using the connector https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

It should work

If not then,

For installing **mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl** you must be running Python3.8 (ideally 64 bit Windows)

For installing **mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl** you must be running Python3.8 (ideally 32 bit Windows)

For installing **mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl** you must be running Python3.7 (ideally 64 bit Windows)

Check this answer also:
[.whl is not supported wheel on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659519/whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in c:\users\busra\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.4.6)                              ı'am trying to run ''python manage.py makemigrations''

Answer (score 0):

After hours of installing and uninstalling visual studio build tools, I later installed visual studio build tools for 2019, it didn't work, then I upgraded my python version from 3.7.2 to 3.10 then deleted the old python version totally then `pip install mysqlclient` finally worked. So I'm not sure if it was the visual studio build tools or python upgrade so...